# "ping: unknown host www.google.com"

Tags: networking, dns, proxy

My college uses a proxy server say `172.21.0.11,port:3128` and when I try to `ping www.google.com` in terminal I'm getting an error as `ping: unknown host www.google.com`

Without setting proxy we can only open my college site in a browser.So, when I tried to ping my college site it's working but nothing other than that.
Please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably going to be easiest to use the Add Network function in System Settings.  There's a screen that has the option for setting a Proxy.  I believe it's System Settings --> Network --> Proxy